# How can i show cursor movement while the speak function is executing using freetts in java?

Tags: java

I am trying that the cursor moves continuously along with the rate of speech.I am getting the speech from the point where the cursor is placed but i m unable to make cursor move along with the speech.Am using freetts and doing it in java.How can i implement it?

```
public class convert extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  String pagenew;// contains the string which is to be spoken
  VoiceManager voiceManager=VoiceManager.getInstance();
  Voice sp;
  Thread t,tcursor;
  CursorMov cm;
  int curpos;
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(sp!=null){
        sp.deallocate();
        sp=null;
    }
    sp=voiceManager.getVoice("kevin16");
    sp.allocate();
    curpos=jTextArea1.getCaretPosition();
    pagenew=page.substring(curpos);
    t=new Thread(new SpeakThread(sp,pagenew));
    t.start();
  }
}

public class SpeakThread implements Runnable{
  Voice spk;
  String pgnew;
  SpeakThread(Voice spnew,String pg){
    spk=spnew;
    pgnew=pg;
  }
  public void run(){
    spk.speak(pgnew);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: i have given d code, if you cud please help..thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, and poorly worded.

I'd need more information to judge whether I can help you further, with the context of your implementation, but heres some sample code to help you control cursor movement.

```
try {
    // Screen cords.
    int xCoord = 500;
    int yCoord = 500;

    // Movement
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(xCoord, yCoord);
} catch (AWTException e) {
}
```